# Google Calendar sample gives 503 error (Service Unavailable) when deployed

Tags: javascript, web, google-calendar-api, google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

I am trying to play with the example at [Building conferencing add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/build-conference-addons) and [Building conferencing add-ons sample](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample).

I deployed my example conferencing add-on to my google account and tried to test. But It was failed to create conference and give me `503 error (Service Unavailable)`.

[image]

[image: Response Header]

[image: Response Message]

Actually I am beginner in Google Conference Add-Ons.
It says 'The service is currently unavailable'. Is that right? Or Do I have to do something more to make it available?

Thank you.

PS: the follow link is the source code that i used.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uWtscnOu5UXy57EZ1isNufTofunN0jPC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank lamblichus for your reply, As I said, I am beginner in Google Calendar Conference Add-on. Yes, I need to connect to the third-part conf system. Honestly I don't know how to implement and I was going to learn and implement it. But I tried to test with dummy data. I think you can see the dummy data in create3rdPartyConference function (see CreateConf.gs). I am not sure that was problem. If you have sample code, i hope you share that with me. Or Could you guide me what was problem. the source code that i linked is my full source code. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: The exact code for this would depend on which third party you want to add the conference for, but connecting to this will probably involve making an API call to the third party, either with the Apps Script [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) or via UrlFetch. See [this](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/create-conference#creating_the_third-party_conference). Check the 3rd party documentation for info on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem yesterday, corrected by adding "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale" in oauthScopes